# How can I create a folder with the same name as the file names in that folder?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

What I want to accomplish can be done with `for %%i in (*) do md "%%~ni"` however this only works if my batch file is in the same folder as the files I want to process. I want to run a batch file from a another folder.

This is what I have tried so far and it's not working. It is still creating the folders in the same folder I run the batch file.

```
for %%i in ("D:\test1\*") do  md "D:\test2\"  "%%~ni"
```

What am I doing wrong? I have not written a script before.

Comment: Your `md` command will create two directories, `"D:\test2\"` and `"%%~ni"`. Since the latter is simply a name with no drive/directory component, it will be created in the current directory. Since the first already exists, you will get an error message which you could suppress by appending ` 2>nul` to the command, noting that this would suppress any error message, regardless of which directory-create failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the path with the name
like this

```batch-file
for %%i in ("D:\test1\*") do  md "D:\test2\%%~ni"
```